# VB 6.0 debugging breakpoint doesn't hit

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a VB 6.0 Project having Class (cls) files. When I start (Debug) my project, and try to execute following statement in Classic ASP page,

```
Set objMyObject = Server.CreateObject("ProjName.ClassName")
```

No breakpoint is hit and following error occurs.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'  ActiveX component can't
>   create object

While if I use the same statement in another VB Project (test project) then breakpoint hits with no error.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What happens if you catch the error and retry a few times?

Comment: Clearly the test project has that class in it - the other project does not, and is therefore trying to find ProjName.ClassName as an external COM object and is failing.  Retrying is going to do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Well you are trying to create an instance of a COM object with the name  'ProjName.ClassName' - which is unlikely to be a real COM object.

Either your COM class needs to be one that has been registered in Windows, or it needs to be a class defined within your VB project.

The example in MSDN is:

```
 Sub CreateADODB()
    Dim adoApp As Object
    adoApp = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
End Sub
```

Where ADODB.Connection is a COM class that has been previously registered in Windows.  The code you have provided above is trying to instantiate a non existant class (unless it is already within the same VB project).

You say that the other project this works, then I will hazard a guess that the test project has a class called ClassName.

Ok -Updated.  The error code is not 'DLL Missing' - It is likely to be some reason why the COM object could not be instantiated.  The following Microsoft support page suggests some reasons and ways of tracking down the problem.  Its likely to be some sort of missing dependency to the DLL.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194801

Comment: Yes, that other project is VB 6.0 exe project and is on same PC.
However about registering the COM, I am accessing it after registering in Windows using regsvr32 <dllpath> command.
if I do not register then I get this following error.

Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' 
Server.CreateObject Failed

Comment: So you created a project with the name "ProjName" and it contains a public class called "ClassName" and you registered it in Windows?  You still get this error in the other project?

Comment: If I register OR just debug the main Project, (other) test project runs fine. But in Classic ASP page, it gives error.

Comment: Is the Test Project the project that actually defines ProjName.ClassName?  Its not clear from what you have written. Are there 3 entities here - a DLL with ProjName.ClassName in it - a test ASP project that works and a main ASP project that does not?

Comment: I have added a MS article suggesting how to track down reasons for this error to my answer.

Comment: - A = Actual Main VB COM+ Project (having ProjName.ClassName) 
- B = Actual Main Classic ASP Project
- C = Test VB exe Project (not ASP project)

- If DLL of A is registered OR in debug mode, everything works fine with C but not with B in any case.

- With B, it works (partially) only if I add the DLL in MTS Server, but I want to debug the code of A when B calls it.

Comment: Ah, this is a COM+ project.  Well unfortunately I can't explain the behaviour you are now describing and have never used COM+.  Perhaps you should re-ask this question but lay it out a bit more like you have now, and adding in the COM+/MTS stuff.  I suggest you close this question and re-ask and see how you get on.